# Displaying specific Data from SQL Database without a Column to filter by. (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatableadapters

I have a `DataGridView` which is displaying `Data` from `dbo.tblAttendanceTimes` using `tblAttendanceTimesTableAdapter.GetDataBy(intEmployee)`

So obviously it will display all the `Data` for the selected Employee.

The Employees are split in to 3 groups. What i would like to do is display all records that have a value of `0` in the `[intApprovedOvertime]` `Column` in `dbo.tblAttendanceTimes` for the particular group i am viewing.

Just with the `GetDataBy(intEmployee)` is making that difficult, there is no `[intAttendanceGroup]` `Column` in that `Table` or i could just `GetDataBy(intAttendanceGroup)`

At the moment i have all the `pk` Values` for the Employees in the group but i'm struggling to retrieve all records for that Employee display them then do the next Employee and add to previously displayed.

I hope i am making sense, please ask for any other information you'd like.

Comment: Why you just don't do a proper SQL request: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE intApprovedOvertime = 0`

Comment: I had thought i could do that for each Employee, then i wasn't sure how i could put them all together and display them.

Comment: If i did that request as it is it would retrieve all the records where as i only want the ones from specific Employees

Comment: you said you just wanted the employees which had value of 0 no? If no please specify exactly what data you want to retrieve

Comment: I want to retrieve all rows from `dbo.tblAttendanceTimes` that has a Value of 0 in `[intApprovedOvertime]` where the fkEmployee = pkEmployee and display them in a `DataGridView` for several pkEmployees

Comment: well there you go you completed your request on your own: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE intApprovedOvertime = 0 AND fkEmployee = pkEmployee` Then just as a reader to loop through the results and add them to the DGV

Comment: You know what i was thinking that as i typed it, It really helps to talk it through with someone to be honest. Thank you!
This really had me stumped for a while as well! now i feel a bit stupid.

Comment: No problem I didn't want to write the solution directly to make you understand instead of just copy pasting haha ill write you a little solution now ;)

Comment: That's the best way to teach, i appreciate that.

Comment: there you go ;)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, i had to leave the computer for a bit so a late reply but thanks again.

Comment: don't forget mark the Answer if it solved your problem so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions can be interesting:

- Linking the database result directly to the DGV very good for easy update but less to move the rows if that's needed
- Inserting the data from the query as rows for that you need first define the columns of the DGV **DataGridView2.Columns.Add()**

**1/**

```
Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("YOUR SQL CONNECTION STRING")
    Dim sqlString As String = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE intApprovedOvertime = 0 AND fkEmployee = pkEmployee"
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Table")
    ds.Dispose()
    da.Dispose()
    SqlConnection.ClearPool(con)
End Using
```

**2/**

```
Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("YOUR SQL CONNECTION STRING")
 Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE intApprovedOvertime = 0 AND fkEmployee = pkEmployee", con)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            DataGridView1.Columns.Rows.Add(reader(0), reader(1))
        End While
End Using
```

In number 2 you need to remember to adapt **reader(x)** to the number of values you need to add to your Row. You can also get just certain column through:

```
"SELECT Table.Name, Table.Position FROM Table WHERE intApprovedOvertime = 0 AND fkEmployee = pkEmployee"
```

There might be few little syntax mistakes I didn't have the IDE with me haha.